# SQL Script to Insert Data From Table1 to Table2 if Employee doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to write a script to Insert data from Table1 to Table2, only if Employee is in Table1 and not in Table2 or if Employee Information changes from Table1 to Table2 adding a changedate.

- Table1: EmployeeNumber, Name, HireDate, Termdate
- Table2: EmployeeNumber, Name, HireDate, Termdate, ChangeDate (date of update to db) getdate()

Sample data:

Table1:

```
EmployeeNumber - Name - HireDate - TermDate
-------------------------------------------
1234           - Ted  - 8-12-1980 -  NULL
9632           - Josh - 1-1-2019  - 3-29-2019
5678           - Jeff - 3-29-2019 - NULL
```

Table2:

```
EmployeeNumber - Name - HireDate - TermDate  - ChangeDate
---------------------------------------------------------
1234          -  Ted - 8-12-1980 -NULL -      8-12-1980
9632          -  Josh - 1-1-2019 - NULL -      1-1-2019
```

I've tried several Insert and Update query's with no luck.

This query works to insert a record that doesn't exist.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 ([EmployeeNumber], [Name], [HireDate], [Termdate], [ChangeDate])
    SELECT 
        *, GETDATE() AS 'ChangeDate'
    FROM 
        Table1
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT [EmployeeNumber] 
                    FROM Table2 
                    WHERE Table1.[EmployeeNumber] = Table2.[EmployeeNumber])
```

After the query runs, Table2 should look like:

Table2:

```
EmployeeNumber - Name - HireDate - TermDate  - ChangeDate
---------------------------------------------------------
1234            - Ted  -   8-12-1980 - NULL      -      8-12-1980
9632            - Josh -   1-1-2019  - NULL      -      1-1-2019
9632            - Josh -   1-1-2019  - 3-26-2019 -      3-29-2019
5678            - Jeff -   3-29-2019 - NULL      -      3-29-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking but I think the method you are looking for is [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Good luck!